# Ubuntu desktop application with facebook

Tags: facebook, ubuntu, monodevelop, gtk#

I am developing a GTK# application for ubuntu desktop. The main functionality includes getting Facebook live-feed and Notification etc after authentication. 
I have registered the app on developers.facebook got the app-id and all, but I can't find any resources for desktop app development and that's where I am stuck.

I am just starting up with Ubuntu development so please don't mind the vague idea of the problem. Ubuntu developers here please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a GUI designer like Glade:

> Glade can be used with the Glade# bindings to easily design GUI
>   applications. A GUI designer called [Stetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stetic) is integrated with the
>   [MonoDevelop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MonoDevelop) IDE.